# How to update the value pointed to by a pointer to NULL in c

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, null

I have a Linked list and head pointer is the pointer to the head of the list.

```
struct ListNode *head;
```

If I introduce another slow pointer here like this,

```
struct ListNode *slow = head;
```

If I move the slow pointer as `slow = slow->next` so that it points to some other node in the list and if I want to update this node pointed by the slow pointer to `NULL`, I could do
`slow = NULL`.

But this does not update the original list and if I want to make changes to the original list I would need to update this  *slow instead of just the pointer slow.
I tried something like this

```
*slow = *((struct ListNode*)0);
```

But that does not work. How do make this change ?

Comment: It's not clear exactly which pointer you're trying to set to `NULL`. If you want to change the pointer that was previously `slow->next`, you need to save that before you do `slow = slow->next`.

Comment: it could be any pointer in the linked list. I wanted to move slow pointer to any node and make that NULL. That way when I print the list pointed by the head I should not go past the NULL node. That means I need to change the original list with the help of slow pointer

Comment: But you have to set the `next` pointer of the *previous* node to do that. You can't set a node itself to `NULL`, because a node is not a pointer.

Comment: Why do you want to set a pointer in a node to NULL? Are you trying to delete a node or split the linked list? And, there is no null-node, there can be a node with a pointer with null value; usually the tail-end of the linked-list.  You need to `free()` the nodes after dropping them off the linked-list, to prevent memory-leaks.

Comment: Can I do this by declaring slow as a double pointer ?

Comment: Why do you call it `slow`? it's not slow by any measure. [linked-list-set-3-deleting-node](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-3-deleting-node/) & [delete-a-linked-list-node-at-a-given-position](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-a-linked-list-node-at-a-given-position/)

Comment: I am trying to delete a node. What if that node is a tail node ? I want to make the tail  node NULL. I can always set the next pointer of prev node to NULL. But I am trying to understand if I can do this any other way

Comment: @priti Yes, you can use a double-pointer, eg: `struct ListNode **slow = &head; while (*slow != NULL) { if (some condition) { *slow = NULL; break; } slow = &((*slow)->next); }`

Comment: You could've lead your question with that, you're trying to delete middle node of a linked list. Nearly an hour later! Again, you delete the pertinent code from question.

Comment: @priti just be aware that simply setting the pointer to NULL will leak memory if the nodes are allocated dynamically, so be sure to free the "deleted" node first.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : one more question. what is the difference between                       
 slow = &((*slow)->next);
        
     and  *slow = (*slow)->next;  because the first one works and the second one does not.

Comment: @priti `slow = &((*slow)->next);` updates `slow` itself to now point at `next` itself, whereas `*slow = (*slow)->next;` updates the `ListNode*` pointer which `slow` is pointing at to now point at the `ListNode` object which `next` is pointing at.